# jFileChooser program keeps running

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

This program grabs the text from a text file and puts it into a string named textFile. 
The issue I am having is after this program executes the program continues to run and i need to kill it manually to stop the program. I don't understand why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

code:

```
  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.FileReader;
  import java.io.IOException;


  public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {

    //selecting the txt file gui
    JFileChooser jFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    int result = jFileChooser.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());
    java.io.File selectedFile = jFileChooser.getSelectedFile();

    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        // System.out.println("Selected file: " + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error selecting file");
    }

    String textFile = "";

    try {
        //start filereader and buffered reader to read txt file that was selected
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(selectedFile);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();

        while(line != null) {
            textFile += line;
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        fileReader.close();

    } catch (Exception error) {
        System.out.println("Error selecting file\n");
        error.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(textFile);
 }
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the program continues to ride` ? How do you know ?

Comment: sorry i meant Program continues to run. Program needs to be manually killed in terminal or thru IDE

Comment: Using a debugger -- which line does it get stuck on?

Comment: Replace `jFileChooser.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());` with `jFileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);` - That will fix it.

Comment: That worked. Thanks